# Glib hash table - key doesn't exists

Tags: c, hashtable, glib

I'm working on a program, which uses Glib's hash table. When the program starts, it reads a file, and fill the hash table based those datas. When the program runs, the user gives their datas, and code checks the key exists - if yes, update the value, if not, insert a new key.

Here is the sample:

```
    // fill hash with data's
    datastore = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);
    while (fgets(inputbuffer, 90, fp) != NULL) {
        parse_utypeline(inputbuffer, udatakey, &udataidx);  // parse line, store fields in udatakey and udataidx
        utype_inc(udatakey, udataidx);  // push to hash
        total++;
    }


    // another part of code, find value of key
    nrofutype = utype_get(utypereclist.udatakey, udatainx);

// implemented functions
int utype_inc(char udatakey[15], int udata) {

    t_utype_rec_udatas *utype_rec_udatas;
    int i;
    gboolean gb;
    GList * hkeys = NULL;
    int gi;

    syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "utype store: %p", datastore);
    gb = g_hash_table_contains(datastore, udatakey);

    if (gb == 0) {
        utype_rec_udatas = g_malloc0(sizeof *utype_rec_udatas);
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            /*
             * every item has derived like this:
             * typedef unsigned char t_utype_rec_udatas[10];
             * t_utype_rec_udatas *utype_rec_udatas;
             */
            (*utype_rec_udatas)[i] = 0;
        }
        g_hash_table_insert(datastore, udatakey, utype_rec_udatas);
    }
    else {
        utype_rec_udatas = g_hash_table_lookup(datastore, udatakey);
    }
    (*utype_rec_udatas)[udata]++;

    gb = g_hash_table_contains(datastore, udatakey);
    if (gb == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        utype_rec_udatas = g_hash_table_lookup(datastore, udatakey);
        return (*utype_rec_udatas)[udata];
    }

}

int utype_get(char udatakey[15], int udata) {
    t_utype_rec_udatas *utype_rec_udatas;
    gboolean gb;

    if (datastore == NULL) {
        syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "store doesn't exists");
        return -1;
    }

    gb = g_hash_table_contains(datastore, udatakey);
    if (gb == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    else {
        utype_rec_udatas = g_hash_table_lookup(datastore, udatakey);
        return (*utype_rec_udatas)[udata];
    }
}
```

The problem is if the code calls utype_get() in later parts, the key didn't exists (which exists, that sure). If I put the syslog lines, and try to catch some data, I see the hash table address is same at every time. If the utype_inc() function log the udatakey, it seems in syslog correctly (I've logged the data from `g_hash_table_get_keys(datastore);`). But if utype_get() called, the `g_hash_table_get_keys(datastore);` gives some very strage info... from *same* store! Here is the syslog lines:

```
Mar 23 18:13:09 basil myprog: udata store: 0x2371400
Mar 23 18:13:09 basil myprog: new udatakey: 'ABCD', udataidx: 0
Mar 23 18:13:09 basil myprog: store value: 1
Mar 23 18:13:09 basil myprog: 0. key: 'ABCD'
Mar 23 18:13:09 basil myprog: size of hash: 1

Mar 23 18:13:13 basil myprog: udata_get - udatakey: '', udataidx: 0
Mar 23 18:13:13 basil myprog: udata_get - size of hash: 1
Mar 23 18:13:13 basil myprog: udata_get - 0. key: '#020#001'
Mar 23 18:13:13 basil myprog: udata_get - udatakey doesn't exists in store: 0x2371400
```

I don't know, what's the #020#001 (I know, that's possible a space, and a 0x01), but why?

Any helps are welcome,

thanks:

a.

Comment: What does valgrind say? It seems like a memory corruption

Comment: I'm not a valgrind expert, here is the relevant output (so, I think this is the relevant part):

==10434== Invalid read of size 1
==10434==    at 0x4C2E4C1: strcmp (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==10434==    by 0x4E6C9B8: g_str_equal (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3800.1)
==10434==    by 0x4E6C3CA: g_hash_table_contains (in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0.3800.1)
==10434==    by 0x423AA3: utype_get (utypeutil.c:119)
...
==10434==  Address 0x7fefffc30 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd

Comment: The first step of code (fill the hash table) runs in another thread, than the second (get, and insert new) - could that occures this problem? The hash table (datastore = g_hash_table_new(g_str_hash, g_str_equal);) had been created in that thread...

Comment: g_hash_table is not thread safe, so yes in general you need to protect access from different thread with a lock, but as you describe it (first step, second step) it sounds like there should be no get or insertions before the filling is done so it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks - I thought it wrong, that isn't in another thread. But someone on Gtk-list helps me, and points this important info:

"Note that neither keys nor values are copied when inserted into the GHashTable, so they must exist for the lifetime of the GHashTable. This means that the use of static strings is OK, but temporary strings (i.e. those created in buffers and those returned by GTK+ widgets) should be copied with g_strdup() before being inserted."

Comment: So, I've created a new char[BIGNR][15] array, and the utype_inc() stores the keys permanently, before it inserts, and the key points to the list item.

Thanks for the help.

a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was:

```
char datakeys[BIGNR][15];

// implemented functions
int utype_inc(char udatakey[15], int udata) {
...
    gb = g_hash_table_contains(datastore, udatakey);

    if (gb == 0) {
        utype_rec_udatas = g_malloc0(sizeof *utype_rec_udatas);
        for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
            /*
             * every item has derived like this:
             * typedef unsigned char t_utype_rec_udatas[10];
             * t_utype_rec_udatas *utype_rec_udatas;
             */
            (*utype_rec_udatas)[i] = 0;
        }
        gi = g_hash_table_size(datastore_store);
        strncpy(datakeys[gi], udatakey, strlen(udatakey));
        g_hash_table_insert(datastore, datakeys[gi], utype_rec_udatas);
    }
...
...
```

Thanks for the help,

a.